# Shrinking input text for speech recognition

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, google-speech-api

```js
   $(function(){
            $('.input').inputfit();
        })

  function startDictation() {

    if (window.hasOwnProperty('webkitSpeechRecognition')) {

      var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();

      recognition.continuous = false;
      recognition.interimResults = false;

      recognition.lang = "en-US";
      recognition.start();

      recognition.onresult = function(e) {
        document.getElementById('transcript').value
                                 = e.results[0][0].transcript;
        recognition.stop();
        document.getElementById('labnol').submit();
      };

      recognition.onerror = function(e) {
        recognition.stop();
      }

    }
  }
```

```css
 html {
            height: 100%;
        }
        body {
            font-family: Helvetica;
              overflow-x: hidden;
              overflow-y: auto;
        }
        .b-input-wrapper {
            height: 70px;
            font-size: 24px;
            text-align: center;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -218px;
            margin-top: -30px;
            width: 436px;
        }
  
  .speak::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #4f30c1 !important;
}

.speak::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #959595 !important;

}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #959595 !important;
}
  
        input {
            width: 250px;
            height: 40px;
            line-height: 30px;
            font-size: 24px;
            text-align: left;
        }
        label {
            font-size: 16px;
            color: #a0a0a0;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tiny Speech</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.inputfit.js"></script>
    <body>
    <div class="b-input-wrapper">
        <input type="text" class="input speak" name="q" id="transcript" placeholder="add your word"/>
    <img class="mic" onclick="startDictation()" src="https://i.imgur.com/cHidSVu.gif"/>       
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to add a jQuery plugin that shrinks *dictated* text to fit within the input field.

So far the plugin only works if text is typed in the field, not if the text is dictated via the microphone / webkitSpeechRecognition (see script webpage below).

[Here's the page](https://rjarz.com/tiny-speech.html)

This was the adjustment I attempted, but still had the same result:

```
 $(function(e){
        $('.input').inputfit().value
                   = e.results[0][0].transcript;
   })
```

How do I get the JavaScript Speech API to work with the jQuery plugin? Is that not possible?

Comment: You can include a link for reference, but please puts all of the relevant code **in the body** of the question, preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). The link could go stale over time and render your question useless to others.

Comment: The snippet is added